# How to do people search mulitple names at a time in Linkedin javascript API

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I am able to search one person at a time by using

```
IN.API.PeopleSearch()
      .fields("id", "firstName", "lastName","emailAddress","headline","industry","pictureUrl","positions",
            "summary","numConnections")
    .params({
      "first-name": firstName,
      "last-name": lastName
    })
    .result(function(result, metadata) {
        alert(result.people.values);
}
```

how to search with multiple names something like

```
.params({
          "first-name": firstName1,firstName2,firstName3
          "last-name": lastName1,lastName2,lastName3
        })
```

is there anything like that, please suggest me.

Comment: I'm not sure but I'd assume they send multiple requests...

Comment: am ok if it is sending multiple requests, but at a time can i get the single response out of it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api) :

> - Multiple words should be joined using a space. Since you need to URL
>     encode input, this translates to %20. For example, Andrew%20Clark.
> - When you pass in multiple words, we search for all words in the string
>     without regard to the order in which they are passed in. In keywords
>     this means the words can appear in any of the fields searched.

Try this :

```
.params({
      "first-name": firstName + " " + firstName2 + " " + firstName3, //You might need to Url encode the string
      "last-name": lastName
    })
```

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(num-results,people:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,headline,industry,picture-url,positions,summary,num-connections))?first-name=ramesh%2520swapna&last-name=kotha%2520kotha this is not giving any results?